# Are Trojan Horse virus? (or is it a matter of debate?)

Tags: virus, trojan

Trojan is a malware, no doubt. But is it a virus? 
While googled, got the following,

> A Trojan horse may also be referred to as a Trojan horse virus, but
>   that is technically incorrect. Unlike a computer virus, a Trojan horse
>   is not able to replicate itself, nor can it propagate without an end
>   user's assistance. [Ref.](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Trojan-horse)

But in the book of Matt Bishop, "Computer Security: Art and Science", It says

> Trojan horses can make copy of themselves

- which means it is a virus.

Is is it a matter of debate or a matter of state (i.e. depends on the specific Trojan on how it behaves, can replicate or not).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, in fact, I found the difference between the Trojan and the virus. But the Trojan acts differently in different cases. It may reproduce itself (characteristics of virus) or may not have that capability. I need to clear this in a theoretical level for the purpose of my study. I hope it helps me to clear my perspective. Thanks again.

Comment: IMO both terms just emphasize an aspect of behavior of a piece of malware. (Trojans deceive, viruses replicate.) Beyond that, definitions can vary and overlap.